# NodeJS and mongo: insertMany changing value from data in the callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodes

If have this piece of code where I´m inserting many items in a mongodb node:

```
const extractions = [{ name: 'xpto' }, { name: 'other xpto' }]
console.log('extractions before', extractions)

dbase.collection('someendpoint').insertMany(extractions, (err, data) => {
  console.log('extractions after', extractions)
})
```

The weird thing is that the inserMany() method is changing the `extractions` const (adding the _id to each item), as follows below:

The output:

> extractions before [ { name: 'xpto' }, { name: 'other xpto' } ]
>   extractions after [ { name: 'xpto', _id: 5b59faf872d33e53c8db4f65 },
>   { name: 'other xpto', _id: 5b59faf872d33e53c8db4f66 } ]

Am I missing something? Is this expected? How can it change the value from a const?
Node is version 8.11.3, mongo is mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.5-rc0

Comment: The array is static, that doesn't mean that you cannot change its properties. `extractions.push(sth)` does also work

Comment: yes, it is expected. `const` might not be ideal word choice, but if you think about it as a reference to the object (you realise the array is an object, don't you?), it might make more sense to you. The reference to `extractions` didn't change. Elements within array did, but they are not `const`.  You can even do `const foo = {bar:1}; foo.baz = 2;` - changing object doesn't change the `const` reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:- Behaviour of CONST keyword in Javascript?

Answer:- The **const** declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its parameters) can be altered. [More Info on CONST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Question 2:- insertMany() behaviour, is this expected?

Answer:- 
If the document does not specify an **_id** field, then mongod adds the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the **_id** field, but the **mongod** will create and populate the **_id** if the driver or application does not.

If the document contains an **_id** field, the _id value must be unique within the collection to avoid duplicate key error. [More info on insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)